# how to change value of textfield of HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<head>
<script type="javascript">
function display()
    {
        document.getElementById("textField1").value = "abc";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" action="http://google.com">

<input id="textField1" type="text" value="0" align="right" size="13"/><br>

<input id="button1" type="button" value="1" onclick="display()">
</form>
</body>
```

but the value of textfield is not changing.

Any Ideas what am i doing wrong ??

Comment: i want it to change from "0" to "abc"
well actually i am creating a calculator and i will pass "1" but in near future, when this issue is resolved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

instead of

```
<script type="javascript">
```

. I believe the latter is not a valid syntax.

Removing the `type` attribute entirely works as well:

```
<script>
```

Comment: Better to remove it entirely.

Comment: I was gonna say, append this to mention that you can just do <script> and most modern web browsers default to javascript

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it works but is it clean? Stack Overflow includes the `type` attribute.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes. The [default for `type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-script-element.html#attr-script-type) is and always has been JavaScript. Code Bundle says "most modern web browsers" but it's not most, it's **all**, modern right the way through to "ancient" from the mid 90's.

Answer (score 4):

Your line

```
document.getElementById("textField1").value = "abc";
```

is correct, try

```
    <head>
<script>
function display() {
        document.getElementById("textField1").value = "abc";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" action="http://google.com">

<input id="textField1" type="text" size="13" value="clear" /><br>

<input type="button" onclick="display()">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `type` from your `script` tag. It's incorrect and making the browser not treat the `script` contents as JavaScript. [Here it is not working](http://jsbin.com/aqokax/1), and [here it is working](http://jsbin.com/aqokax/2) (with the `type="javascript"` removed).

Answer (score 3):

It has to be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display()
    {
        document.getElementById("textField1").value = "abc";
    }
</script>
```

and not

```
<script type="javascript">
function display()
    {
        document.getElementById("textField1").value = "abc";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the text field is not having id attribute and having name attribute then,

use

```js
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value="ert";
```

getElementsByName() returns an array of objects with that specific name,that's why we are using the index 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, it works fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2Xab/).

I only speculate, but you could try to either delete the type attribute of the script-tag, or change it to `type="text/javascript"` which would be the proper type to use. If you don't specify it, the browser will consider it as JavaScript by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually correct, but if it doesn't work try like this:

```
document.getElementById("textfield1").innerHtml = "ABC";
```